# How to configure hostname resolution to use a custom DNS server in Java?

Tags: java, networking, dns

[java.net.InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) resolves hostnames using the local machine's default host-name resolver by default:

> Host name-to-IP address resolution is accomplished through the use of a combination of local machine configuration information and network naming services such as the Domain Name System (DNS) and Network Information Service(NIS). The particular naming services(s) being used is **by default the local machine configured one**. For any host name, its corresponding IP address is returned. <sup>[[source]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)</sup>

How can we configure this behavior without modifying the local machine's default hostname resolver?

For example, is there anyway to configure [java.net.InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) such that it resolves host names through OpenDNS (208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220) or Google Public DNS (2001:4860:4860::8888, 2001:4860:4860::8844)?

Or is the only solution to explicitly create DNS packet requests, send them to the servers through either [java.net.DatagramSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) or [java.net.Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), and parse the responses?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java 9 removed this capability.  You will need to use a third party DNS client library.

If you are using Java 8 or older you can do:

You can set the system property `sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers` as documented by [this site.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)

Comment: As documented in the same site: "These properties may not be supported in future releases." Is there another way to achieve that?

Comment: No.  Not if you want to use `java.net.InetAddress`.  If you're ok using a different mechanism then you could of course use a 3rd party DNS library ( e.g. [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/) ).

The only real reason the properties might change is if Oracle overhauls the `java.net` implementation in some future version of Java.  If this happens they will likely provide an a new solution to this problem at that time as well.

Comment: They overhauled `java.net` in Java 9, so the `sun.net` classes needed to pull this off no longer exist.

Comment: You are correct.  You will need to use a third party library starting with Java 9.

Answer (score 11):

with the following Interface and allowing access to java.net.* it is possible to use own DNS provider with JDK8 and JDK9. The new Provider is installed via
"INameService.install(new MyNameService());"

```
public interface INameService extends InvocationHandler {
    public static void install(final INameService dns) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, ClassNotFoundException {
        final Class<?> inetAddressClass = InetAddress.class;
        Object neu;
        Field nameServiceField;
        try {
            final Class<?> iface = Class.forName("java.net.InetAddress$NameService");
            nameServiceField = inetAddressClass.getDeclaredField("nameService");
            neu = Proxy.newProxyInstance(iface.getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] { iface }, dns);
        } catch(final ClassNotFoundException|NoSuchFieldException e) {
            nameServiceField = inetAddressClass.getDeclaredField("nameServices");
            final Class<?> iface = Class.forName("sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService");
            neu = Arrays.asList(Proxy.newProxyInstance(iface.getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] { iface }, dns));
        }
        nameServiceField.setAccessible(true);
        nameServiceField.set(inetAddressClass, neu);
    }

    /**
     * Lookup a host mapping by name. Retrieve the IP addresses associated with a host
     *
     * @param host the specified hostname
     * @return array of IP addresses for the requested host
     * @throws UnknownHostException  if no IP address for the {@code host} could be found
     */
    InetAddress[] lookupAllHostAddr(final String host) throws UnknownHostException;

    /**
     * Lookup the host corresponding to the IP address provided
     *
     * @param addr byte array representing an IP address
     * @return {@code String} representing the host name mapping
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     *             if no host found for the specified IP address
     */
    String getHostByAddr(final byte[] addr) throws UnknownHostException;

    @Override default public Object invoke(final Object proxy, final Method method, final Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        switch(method.getName()) {
        case "lookupAllHostAddr": return lookupAllHostAddr((String)args[0]);
        case "getHostByAddr"    : return getHostByAddr    ((byte[])args[0]);
        default                 :
            final StringBuilder o = new StringBuilder();
            o.append(method.getReturnType().getCanonicalName()+" "+method.getName()+"(");
            final Class<?>[] ps = method.getParameterTypes();
            for(int i=0;i<ps.length;++i) {
                if(i>0) o.append(", ");
                o.append(ps[i].getCanonicalName()).append(" p").append(i);
            }
            o.append(")");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(o.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was workign great but I think doesn't work any longer with JDK 18.  Any ideas how to achieve this in JDK 18?

Comment: Hi, under JDK 18 this can be done via InetAddressResolverProvider and InetAddressResolver and define the Implementation Class under META-INF/services/java.net.spi.InetAddressResolverProvider

Answer (score 11):

Java provided a new system parameter `jdk.net.hosts.file` for adding customized DNS records, as specified in the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/InetAddress.java#L939)

```
 * The HostsFileNameService provides host address mapping
 * by reading the entries in a hosts file, which is specified by
 * {@code jdk.net.hosts.file} system property
 *
 * <p>The file format is that which corresponds with the /etc/hosts file
 * IP Address host alias list.
 *
 * <p>When the file lookup is enabled it replaces the default NameService
 * implementation
 *
 * @since 9
 */
private static final class HostsFileNameService implements NameService {
```

Example: we can start a Java application with JVM Option

- `-Djdk.net.hosts.file=/path/to/alternative/hosts_file`

Where `hosts_file` content could be:

```
127.0.0.1    myserver-a.local
10.0.5.10    myserver-b.local
192.168.0.1  myserver-c.local
```

It will do the DNS trick based on the `hosts_file`

Comment: Can we do it programmatically?

Comment: @NathanB 
- For me, in current environment I use a shell script dynamically generate the hosts_file before starting the Java application.
- I did not find the API to dynamically add the DNS record at runtime yet, unfortunately

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find either, and it's a shame. Java should add this functionality as it is essential, both for testing, e.g. multiple servers on different IP addresses and also it can save time to avoid getting to DNS, but rather directly reach to the right IP.

Answer (score 8):

For Java versions up to 8, here is the code I wrote to hard-code a `foo` system name DNS resolution in Java for test cases to pass. Its avantage is to append your specific entrie(s) to default Java runtime DNS resolution.

I recommend **not to run it in production**. Forced reflective access and Java runtime non-public implementation classes are used !

```
private static final String FOO_IP = "10.10.8.111";

/** Fake "foo" DNS resolution */
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public static class MyHostNameService implements sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService {
    @Override
    public InetAddress[] lookupAllHostAddr(String paramString) throws UnknownHostException {
        if ("foo".equals(paramString) || "foo.domain.tld".equals(paramString)) {
            final byte[] arrayOfByte = sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV4(FOO_IP);
            final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(paramString, arrayOfByte);
            return new InetAddress[] { address };
        } else {
            throw new UnknownHostException();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String getHostByAddr(byte[] paramArrayOfByte) throws UnknownHostException {
        throw new UnknownHostException();
    }
}

static {
    // Force to load fake hostname resolution for tests to pass
    try {
        List<sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService> nameServices =
            (List<sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService>)
            org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.readStaticField(InetAddress.class, "nameServices", true);
        nameServices.add(new MyHostNameService());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, but again, to be used with care !

Comment: error: package org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect does not exist - anything we should import?

Answer (score 0):

As Pace indicated, the ability to configure name resolution was removed from the JDK. However, in Java 18, it was replaced with the SPI [java.net.spi.InetAddressResolverProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/net/spi/InetAddressResolverProvider.html).

Between Java 8 and Java 18, as the JDK [Inet4AddressImpl.c](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/native/libnet/Inet4AddressImpl.c#L232-L240) eventually ends up calling `getnameinfo`, you can still intercept that call with `LD_PRELOAD` shadowing.

There are libraries which make this very straightforward, such as [CWrap](https://cwrap.org/).