# Change DNS of HttpUrlConnection

Tags: kotlin, httpurlconnection

Using Kotlin, I'm trying to access an URL that is blocked in my country and I need to change the DNS or turn on VPN to make a successful connection.

Is there any way to change the DNS programmatically, or is there any other suitable solution to this problem.

My code:

```
val url = URL("https://prices2.herokuapp.com/")
val con=url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
con.connectTimeout=5000
val inputstream=con.inputStream
val bufferreader=BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputstream))
bufferreader.forEachLine {
                    data+=it
                }
```

Comment: [This question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647629/how-to-configure-hostname-resolution-to-use-a-custom-dns-server-in-java) might be helpful, or you could look at other libraries that provide hostname resolution. For example, [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-dns/).

Answer (score 0):

Use third-party tools (such as [dnsjava](https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava) or [MiniDNS](https://github.com/MiniDNS/minidns)) to resolve the IP of your target Hostname. And connect to the target server through the IP directly.